How does pyomo handle constraints with equal index
suppose that I have two constraints in pyomo like this
@model.Constraint(model.SKU, model.T)
def r2_security_stock(modelo, sku, t):
    return modelo.SF_T[sku, t] >= modelo.ss_s[sku]
@model.Constraint(model.SKU, model.T)
def r3_prod(modelo, sku, t):
    return modelo.Q_T[sku, t] == modelo.tl_s[sku] * modelo.L_T[sku, t]

Does pyomo loop over each one individually, or does automatically detect this situation and perform only one loop?

For each constraint Pyomo consider its own index set  unless you group the constraints. An example:
model.const1 = ConstraintList()
model.const2 = ConstraintList()
for i in set1:
    for r in set2 - {1, 2}:
        model.const1.add(model.w[r-1, i] >= model.c[r-1, i])
        model.const2.add(model.w[r-1, i] <= UB*model.z[r, i])

Also you can get the index sets for each constraint as follow:
model.const1.index_set().data()


Is it faster to use the "def" way to define a constraint compared to the manual loops like in your answer?

Pyomo loops through every combination of indices in model.SKU and model.T for each constraint.
